# How to get data from my API call into a variable to place into my HTML

Tags: javascript

So, I am successfully able to call my API and print the data I need to print but the problem is that I need to print the data to my web app and am a little lost on how to do so. I currently am using fetch to grab the API data but I do not know what to do from here.

```
function getRecipesFromIngredients(){

var data;

fetch("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=rice%2Cchicken%2Csteak&number=5&ranking=1&ignorePantry=true", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))

.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

}
```

I've tried using my data var in the .then statements with no luck. If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to use your `data` variable because you never assign it a value. The best place would be inside the second `.then()` block once the body of the response has been extracted:

```
fetch("...")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        data = json;
        // Do something with the data...
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Side note: by declaring `data` in your method, you are creating a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) which may not be what you want. The `data` variable will only be accessible to code inside your method. If you want to assign the result to a variable that can be used anywhere, move the declaration outside of the method. Just be aware that you will need to check if `data` has been assigned to before using it or you will run into [null reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) errors.

```
var data;

function getRecipesFromIngredients(){
    ...
    data = json;
    ...
}
```